# How can I tell if an object has a specific overloaded method?

Tags: perl

I want to check if an object has a specific overload method in perl - for example if it has a sub dereferencing overload that would have been defined like this:

```
use overload
    '&{}' => \&_some_sub;

sub some_sub {...}
```

If I dump the symbol table of the package that created the object in question I see the following:

```
[
  "new",
  "import",
  "((",
  "(&{}",
  "ISA",
  "__ANON__",
  "BEGIN",
]
```

Does finding `(&{}` in the symbol table *always* mean that a sub deref methd exists? and does it work for other overloads too (I see `(""` if I overload stringification).

Comment: Do fallbacks matter? For example, if an object overloads `0+` and has fallbacks turned on, then that will automatically allow most numeric operators to work, even without explicitly overloading `+`, `-`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The details of how `overload` works under the hood isn't documented very well, and the first line of the [`IMPLEMENTATION`](https://perldoc.perl.org/overload#IMPLEMENTATION) section is *What follows is subject to change RSN.* So you can't depend on checking the symbol table.

The module does, however, [provide a way](https://perldoc.perl.org/overload#Public-Functions) to see if an operator is overloaded for an object:

> **overload::Method(obj,op)**

> Returns `undef` or a reference to the method that implements `op`.

So you can use

```perl
if (overload::Method($someobj, '&{}')) {
    # Overloaded sub deref
}
```